# Kotlin/Native compilation fails on windows with Java ZipException

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I've created a new Kotlin/Native application using IntelliJ Idea and it fails to compile.
I hadn't change anything.

I'm sure it fails at compilation time because it says "Compilation ended with errors"

Stack trace: [`java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths...`](https://pastebin.com/C65trqMa)

Comment: You need to provide more information. What is the error message? Could you provide a stack trace? Also, are you sure ZipException occurs during the compilation and not on runtime?

Comment: It looks like the compiler was unable to download its dependencies. Probably, the archive was downloaded with an error, but the compiler is not smart enough to clean up and restart. Please try to delete contents of `C:\Users\<UserName>/.konan`, and let everything be re-downloaded.